# Hourly Wage Calculation

Tags: c#, php, pseudocode

I have a database table like this:

```
wagetable
 name     lowhours  highhours  wage 
 Default  0         40         10   
 Default  40        9999       15   
 Brian    0         40         15   
 Brian    40        50         20   
 Brian    50        9999       22   
 Chad     0         40         13   
 Chad     40        9999       17
```

If 'Brian' worked 43.5151587 hours, I want it to figure out that he made (40*15)+(3.5151587*20) = 670.303174.

This is a SQLite database, so I know I will use:

```
SELECT wage FROM wagetable WHERE name LIKE 'Brian' AND 'HourNum' BETWEEN lowhours AND highhours;
```

With a combination of floor and %... I am just not putting the logic together in my head.

Please note answers in C# and PHP accepted, as I can convert the logic to what I need. I am looking for pseudo code but will accept drawn out answers

Edit: please note...The hours worked will never be an exact integer, why I let overlapping happen.

Edit2:

I want to take an employees total hours worked (example: 43.5151587) and then realize that the first 40 hours, he was making standard pay @ $15 an hour. so (40*15)...Then he worked 3.5151587 hours of overtime @ $20 an hour. so (40*15) add to it (3.5151587*20)...The total amount earned was 670.303174

Comment: Hi,
the logic isn't clear to me. The numbers in the text between your sample table don't match the numbers in the table itself - maybe it's easier if you align the two. Elaborating a bit more on your desired behaviour might not hurt either.

Comment: Am I misunderstanding something? `40 * 15 = 600` and `3.5151587 * 20 = 70.303174`, so the total amount earnt was `670.303174`...?

Comment: Sorry, damn windows calculator shot an answer and I took it for granted...

Comment: Did $70 for over a weeks work seem a little low to you? You need a new job! :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I gather from your post (psuedocode):

```
foreach pay_bracket p:
    if hours > p.length
        pay += p.length * p.pay
        hours -= p.length
    else
        pay += hours * p.pay
        end
```

Where `length` is `highhours` - `lowhours` (and that pay brackets are right next to each other, of course).

Comment: pay brackets will not be right next to each other most likely. However I could just take sort them in a sense. Thia is what I wanted though. Thanks

Comment: One thing I want to add, dont forget to set hours to zero in the else statement. :)

Comment: Nevermind, I guess thats the idea why you put end...I didnt implement end :)